# React js - express: res.send Vs res.render Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am building a very small example application to practice a login page. 
I am working with :

1) [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/)

2) [Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/) - in particular with Journal form

3) [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)

After successfully setting up all my components I have a very strange error if I apply the following change in my `index.js` file in charge of rendering my localhost:5000 window

`router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('welcome')); <-- This way works`

`router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome')); <-- This way throws error`

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const app = express();
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('welcome')); // <-- This way works
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome')); // <-- This way throws error
module.exports = router;
```

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Login Page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.send('Login'));
// Register Page
router.get('/register', (req, res) => res.send('Register'));
module.exports = router;
```

**layouts.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/My_KIT.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../components/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <%- body %>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**The error:**

> Error: Failed to lookup view "layout" in views directory
>   "/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/views"
>       at Function.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
>       at /home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express-ejs-layouts/lib/express-layouts.js:113:20
>       at tryHandleCache (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:260:5)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:459:10)
>       at View.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
>       at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express-ejs-layouts/lib/express-layouts.js:77:18)

**What I have done so far:**

1) I thought it was an error due to the `render` method and went to check the [official documentation about it](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) but I didn't see any problem with the small portion of code I wrote.

2) A print screen is also provided if that is easier to understand:

[image: print]

Please point to the right direction for solving this issue

Comment: Why did you reverse the call order of app.use() and app.set() for express-ejs-layouts, compared to [what the readme tells you to use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts#usage)? That said, the error is telling you it can't find the relevant file paths, so: do you have the correct dir built with the correct files in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `view` in the lookup directory with name `welcome`.

When you use `res.send('welcome')` the express will send the response with just `welcome` `text` so it will not look for any `view` pages.

But on the other side, when you use `res.render` it will search for the `template` view with name `welcome.ejs`.

> res.render is used to load up an ejs view file

Create a file in view with `welcome.ejs` and try.

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: That was a silly error! Thank you very much for your help :)